# KeyboardEvent.keyCode deprecated, but what about diacritics?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard-events

We had an interesting bug at the company I work on: we have an application with lots of key shortcuts, including "`" (backtick character), and because [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode` has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), it was changed on a refactor from

```
KeyboardEvent.keyCode === 192
```

to

```
KeyboardEvent.key === '`'
```

This works on keyboards without diacritics activated - for instance, US keyboard with no diacritics where pressing the ` key would immediately write the ` character - while for users with diacritics activated, it would not (on such cases, to type the ` one needs to press the ` key then space), because if you press the key ` and then the letter a, for instance, you get the character à. Apparently with diacritics activated, `KeyboardEvent.key` returns `Dead`, so we had to revert this refactor.

That being said, is there a different option then using this deprecated feature?

Comment: The question is what information do you want to retrieve? I mean the `192` does not necessarily represent  `\``, for a german layout it was e.g. `187`.

Comment: @t.niese The idea was to trigger an event when the user pressed the key above the Tab key.

Comment: So the physical key above the `tab` no matter what it actually is?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. I'm not sure it was tested in other layouts than US, though.

Comment: Ok, because `code` being `Backquote` would equal to the `^` key (the one above the tab key) being pressed on a keyboard with a Germany layout. And when `´` is pressed on a Germany layout you will get `Equal` as `code`. And `\`` does not have a dedicated key, but it is available thought `Shift key`+ `´`.

Comment: So in a nutshell it'd be a world of pain trying to support different keyboard layouts. Gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

You can use KeyboardEvent.code

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code

Comment: Thanks Daniel. On my keyboard (US with dead keys) it returns `KeyboardEvent.key === 'Dead' && KeyboardEvent.code === 'Backquote'`. So the way to go could be testing it with

    KeyboardEvent.key === '`' || (KeyboardEvent.key === 'Dead' && KeyboardEvent.code === 'Backquote')